# Import excel file to wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have an excel file exported from MSSQL Server that contains users & emails & orders

i want to import the users to word press i tried customer import export plugin 
but with no luck at all it gives me an error

any guidance on how can i achieve this ? 
or is it achievable in the 1st place ?
here is the excel file

```
https://gofile.io/?c=XQYZl4
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done if you transform the excel file into an csv one, comma separated

I'm not sure that you can import into multiple tables at once, but if you reorder your file and construct a csv correctly for each entity it might work.

To have an great template example of how to the csv should be created i suggest using the export functionality from wordpress and copy-paste-ing your data into that template.

*also i suggest using google spreadsheets for editing the csv and after the file is ready, you should export as csv comma separated